# Questions about pushout in a suitable model category

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, model-categories

Let us consider a diagram in any suitable( proper) model category as follows:

[image]

Where $X' \to X,$ $Y' \to Y$ and $Z' \to Z$ are weak equivalences and P and P' are the pushout of the diagram $Z' \leftarrow X' \to Y'$ and $Z \leftarrow X \to Y$ respectively. Then my questions are the following:

(1) I think there exists a weak equivalence $P' \to P$ such that the diagram commutes. What should be a detailed proof of it?

(2) What is the pushout of the diagram $Z \leftarrow Z' \to P'?$ My guess is $P$ but I don't have any proof for it.

Thank you so much in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the squares X'Y'XY and X'Z'XZ are commutative in what follows.

(1) is false in general.
Additional assumptions are needed, e.g., that both squares
XYZP and X'Y'Z'P'
are homotopy pushouts.
Under such an assumption, (1) becomes a tautology.

(2) is false.
Counterexample: all spaces are points, except Y=Δ^1.

Comment: One small question. Let us assume that $XYZW$ and $X'Y'Z'W'$ be two commutative diagrams and $XYZP$ and $X'Y'Z'P'$ are two homotopy pushout diagram as you described with an additional condition $W'\to W$ is also a weak equivalence. Then as you said $P' \to P$ is a weak equivalence. But is it true that $P'PW'W$ is a commutative square?

Comment: @Surojit: This claim is false in general.  It is true under additional assumptions, such as the commutativity of the squares Y'YW'W and Z'ZW'W.

Comment: @Surojit: It seems like we may have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.  What exactly is the original problem that you were trying to solve?

Comment: @Dimitripavlov: Consider we have two commutative square $XYZW$ and $X'Y'Z'W'$ with the pointwise weak equivalence between them - that is the morphisms $X'\to X, Y' \to Y, Z'\to Z$ and $W' \to W$ are weak equivalences. Now consider the homotopy pushouts $P'$ and $P$ of the diagram $Z' \leftarrow X' \to Y'$ and $Z \leftarrow X \to Y$ respectively. Then there exists a weak equivalence $P' \to P$ such that all the squares in that big diagram are commutative. Here ABCD means $\begin{array}{ccc} A & \xrightarrow{} & B \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ C & \xrightarrow{} & D \end{array}$

Comment: @Surojit: Are the squares X'XY'Y and X'XZ'Z commutative in your problem?

Comment: Yes, these square are commutative.

Comment: @Surojit: Then a positive answer is given by Proposition 13.5.3 of Hirschhorn's Model Categories and Their Localizations.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Another small and different doubt. Let $D_1:=XYZW_1$ and $D_2:=XYZW_2$ be two diagrams in the proper model category $\mathcal{C}$. Let $P$ be the homotopy pushout of $Z \leftarrow X \to Y$. So, we have canonical maps $\beta_i: P \to W_i$ for i=1,2. If $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are equivalent in the Arrow category of $\mathcal{C}$ then is it possible to construct equivalence between $D_1$ and $D_2$ in the homotopy category of the diagrams?

Comment: @Surojit: “equivalent in the Arrow category” can mean many different things, but if it means weak equivalence in the slice category P/C (which yields a weak equivalence W_1→W_2), then a weak equivalence between the diagrams D_1 and D_2 can be constructed by taking identities for X, Y, Z, and the given map W_1→W_2.

Comment: $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are equivalent in the homotopy category of the Arrow category means: there exists a zigzag of weak equivalence between $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$. That is \begin{array}{ccccccccc} P & \xleftarrow{\sim} & U_1 & \xrightarrow{\sim} &\cdots &\xleftarrow{\sim} & U_n & \xrightarrow{\sim} & P \\ \downarrow{\beta_1}  & & \downarrow & & & &  \downarrow & & \downarrow{\beta_2} \\ W_1& \xleftarrow{\sim} & U_1 & \xrightarrow{\sim} &\cdots &\xleftarrow{\sim} & U_n & \xrightarrow{\sim} & W_2\end{array}

Comment: @Surojit: This is false.  Take X=∅, Y=Z=A, W_1=W_2=A⊔B, such that A and B are not weakly equivalent, ∅ and A are not weakly equivalent, and there is a map f: A→B.  Denote by κ: A→A⊔B the inclusion as the first summand and by λ: A→A⊔B the composition of f and the inclusion as the second summand.  For the first square, take Y→W_1 and Z→W_2 to be κ and λ, and for the second square take them to be λ and κ.  Then P=A⊔A, and the map β_1 and β_2 are weakly equivalent, using a map P→P that permutes A and A and therefore is a weak equivalence.  But the diagrams are not weakly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Let \begin{array}{ccc} X & \xrightarrow{} & Y\\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ Z & \xrightarrow{} & W\end{array} be a diagram and $X,Y,Z$ be cofibrant with $X\to Y$ and $X\to Z$ be cofibrations. Also, let us assume that $W$ be a fibrant in a proper model category. Let $\beta: C \to W$ be the pushout of $Z  \leftarrow X \to Y$ and $\alpha: X \to P$ be the pullback of $Z \to W \leftarrow Y.$ Do you know any kind of relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: @Surojit: What kind of relationship are you looking for?  Note that P need not be a homotopy pullback unless Z→W or Y→W is a fibration.

Comment: We can assume $Z\to W$ and $Y\to W$ are fibrations. Can we have a map from $P \to C$ or $C \to P?$

Comment: @Surojit: A map C→P need not exist in general.  Such a map would have as its components maps of the form Y→Z or Z→Y, and it is possible that there are no such maps at all.  A map P→C likewise need not exist in general, at least if you assume the commutativity of triangles PYC and PZC, since this would require P to factor through both Y and Z inside C, and they can be easily made disjoint.  Why do you want such maps in the first place?

Comment: The real reason as follows: Take two diagrams \begin{array}{ccc}X & \xrightarrow{f} & Y\\ \downarrow{g} & & \downarrow{k}\\ Z & \xrightarrow{h} & W\end{array} and \begin{array}{ccc}X' & \xrightarrow{f'} & Y'\\ \downarrow{g'} & & \downarrow{k'}\\ Z' & \xrightarrow{h'} & W'\end{array}, of the type described above. If $f\sim f', g\sim g', k \sim k', h\sim h' $ and $\beta \sim \beta'$ or $\alpha \sim \alpha'$ then the diagrams are equivalent in the homotopy category of the diagram category that is they are related by the zig-zag of weak equivalences of diagrams.

Comment: That is why I am thinking that there should be some connection between $\alpha$ and $\beta.$